# How to download a file in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I would like to download a file on click, that I get from the database. Example:

```
<a class="document" *ngFor="let document of documents">{{document.documentName }}</a>
```

So ill have multiple documents, and I would like to download the on click, how do I do that?

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

Comment: You specify the URL of the document in `href`. What's the concrete problem?

Comment: I cant specify the URL file is stored in database (something like that backenders told me), from what I found I should do something like this:  window.open(window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([file.document.data])));

Comment: Then put in href the URL of a resource (like `"/downloads/{{ document.id }}"`), and make that resource extract the ID of the document from the URL, get its data out of the database, and send it as a response with the appropriate content-type header.

Comment: Do you have some example of it please? Dont really understand it, haven't done it before

Answer (score 0):

You have to generate a path from database to getting the file. Then only you can achieve it.

```
<a href="yourserverpath" >Download Template</a>
```

(or)

Alternative solution is:

You must save the file in your application

```
<a href="../assets/files/Bulk Item Import.xlsx" >Download Template</a>
```